# ng-repeat not working with multiselect plugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
 <select class="form_control" id="district"  name="district" multiple
        ng-model="$scope.district">
    <option value="{{tp_id}}" ng-repeat="tp_id in district" >{{tp_id}}
    </option>
</select>
```

when i code like this there is no value present for options.
but when i use select option without "multiple" ng-repeat work fine.Kindly help me out where i am doing wrong.
using these libs.enter image description here

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../asset/css/bootstrap-select.css">
```

---

Here code from php side

```
$sql="SELECT * from district";
doLog('[sr_getCampaignData][select district] [sql: ' . $sql . ' ]');
$result=$conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows>0){
   while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
      $district[]=$row['tp_id']; 
   } 
   $response['district']=$district;
   $response['success']=100;
}
```

---

```
$scope.district=response.data.district;
```

where i am getting from response.

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../asset/css/bootstrap-select.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../asset/css/jquery.multiselect.css">
<script src="../assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
</script>
<script src="../asset/js/jquery.multiselect.js"></script> 
<script src="../asset/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../asset/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
```

Comment: use ng-value `<option ng-value="{{tp_id}}" ng-repeat="tp_id in district" >{{tp_id}}</option>`

Comment: When using `<select multiple`, the `ng-model` needs to be an array.

Comment: dear @georgeawg district is an array .Here code from php side $sql="SELECT * from district";
doLog('[sr_getCampaignData][select district] [sql: ' . $sql . ' ]');
$result=$conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows>0){
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $district[]=$row['tp_id'];
    }
    $response['district']=$district;
    $response['success']=100;

}

Comment: $scope.district=response.data.district; where i am getting from response.

Comment: @georgeawg i am using multi select plugin without plugin its working fine but with plugin it is not working

Answer (score 0):

[Check this working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/M3J9VK?p=preview)

There isn't much that I have changed other than `ng-model="$scope.district"` to `ng-model="sel_district"`

1. You are using `$scope` in html, which isn't allowed
2. You are using the same name for `ng-model` that you are using for `ng-repeat` which is also not right.

Comment: i do same but still not working.Can it may be plugins jquery bootstraps versions issue???

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../asset/css/bootstrap-select.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../asset/css/jquery.multiselect.css">
    <script src="../assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../asset/js/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
    <script src="../asset/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../asset/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

Comment: @WasimAkram : NO, it cant be version issue. Check browser console and see what error you are getting

Comment: dear @Shashank Vivek there is no error on console data s available

Comment: @WasimAkram can u create a demo plunkr and share the url ? just like i did for solution